# Want to enable S3 access logging, but how about the logs for the logging bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using CDK and I am trying to comply with this security hub issue:

**S3 bucket server access logging should be enabled**

Thus, I am trying to create one bucket that would contain the access logs of all buckets.

But what about that logging bucket? Wouldn't I have the same security issue on that bucket? Is there any way to fix this using cdk? I am asking about cdk because I know that the logging bucket should be referenced at the moment of creation of the bucket but this can't be done using the cdk, and I'm not even sure if it's a good idea to log the logging bucket access data inside the same one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never be able to be 100% compliant with some of the compliance packs like AWS Foundational Security Best Practices, CIS AWS Foundations Benchmark, etc for this exact reason.

If you log access on the logging bucket you'll end up creating circular logic that will cause your access logs to continue to grow and grow.

Consider suppressing this finding.